# Linear system of ODE and the solution of IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that the matrix $A(t)$ is continuous for $t\in (a,b)$ and $R(\mathbf{x},t)$ is continuous for all $\mathbf{x}$ and $t\in (a,b)$. Prove that the IVP

$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=A(t)\mathbf{x} + R(\mathbf{x},t),$$
$$\mathbf{x} (t_0)=\mathbf{x}^0$$

is equivalent to the integral equation

$$\mathbf{x} (t)= \Phi (t)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)\mathbf{x}^0 +\int_{t_0}^t \Phi (t-s+t_0)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)R(\mathbf{x} (s),s)ds,$$

where $\Phi (t)$ is any fundamental matrix of the homogeneous system

$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=A(t)\mathbf{x}.$$

I have learned a similar theorem (from Birkhoff and Rota's book) that if $A$ is a constant matrix, $\mathbf{b}(t)=(b_1(t),\cdots,b_n(t))$ is continuous, and

$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=A\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}(t),$$
$$\mathbf{x} (t_0)=\mathbf{x}^0$$

then the solution of the above IVP is given by

$$\mathbf{x} (t)= \Phi (t)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)\mathbf{x}^0 +\int_{t_0}^t \Phi (t-s+t_0)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)\mathbf{b}(s)ds.$$

I have tried to mimick that proof but have failed. Please helps.

Comment: this is just the dressed up version of the solution for $\frac{dx}{dt} = ax + r.$ the integral representation is $x= e^{at}x(0) + \int_0^t e^{a(t-s)} r \,ds$

Answer (score 0):

Now I give the detail. It is easy to check that $\mathbf{x}(t_0)=\mathbf{x}^0$. Note that
$$ \Phi (t-s+t_0)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)=\Phi (t)\Phi^{-1}(s) $$
and hence
$$\mathbf{x} (t)= \Phi (t)\Phi^{-1}(t_0)\mathbf{x}^0 +\int_{t_0}^t\Phi (t)\Phi^{-1}(s)R(\mathbf{x} (s),s)ds,$$
or
$$\Phi^{-1}(t)\mathbf{x} (t)=\Phi^{-1}(t_0)\mathbf{x}^0 +\int_{t_0}^t\Phi^{-1}(s)R(\mathbf{x} (s),s)ds,$$
Differentiating w.r.t $t$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
(\Phi^{-1}(t)\mathbf{x} (t))'=\Phi^{-1}(t)R(\mathbf{x} (t),t)
\end{eqnarray}
or
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\Phi^{-1}(t)\mathbf{x} (t)+\Phi^{-1}(t)\mathbf{x}'(t)=\Phi^{-1}(t)R(\mathbf{x} (t),t). $$
Noting $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi^{-1}(t)=-\Phi^{-1}(t)A$, we get
$$ -\Phi^{-1}(t)A\mathbf{x} (t)+\Phi^{-1}(t)\mathbf{x}'(t)=\Phi^{-1}(t)R(\mathbf{x} (t),t) $$
which implies
$$ \mathbf{x}'(t)=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)+R(\mathbf{x} (t),t). $$

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to prove the first IVP (R(x,t)) is equivalent to the integral equation. I tried to mimick the proof of the second IVP which I found in the book but failed. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: @Mayanne, I put the answer in detail.